# JS function not being called?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

im a complete nooblet at javascript so if some one could help me id appreciate it :)

im trying to call my function (questions) from my external js file however its not loading it for what ever reason.any help would be awesome!

HTML file

```
 <section>

    <h3 id="q1" window.onload= "loadQuestion1()" style="color:blue"></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="answers" value="Css is 1" >Answer 1</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 2</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 3</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 4</li>
    </ul>

    </section>
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>
</body>
```

javascript file

```
console.log("53");

var questions = Array["question 1", "question 2", "question 3","question 4" ]

function loadQuestion1(){
console.log("q1");
document.getElementById('q1').innerHTML = "text";
}
function rand(min, max) { 

var offset = min; 
var range = (max - min) + 1; 
var randomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * range) + offset; 
return randomNumber; } 

randomNumber = rand(0, questions.length - 1); 
randomQuestions = questions.[randomNumber];
```

So currently it should load the word "text" but its not loading that for some reason - never mind the actual question.

p.s im trying to make a small quiz app which selects a random question from the array

Comment: The way you've attempted to add the event handler is incorrect. You have to either set the "load" attribute on the `<body>` tag, or else set up the handler in your JavaScript by assigning the function to `window.onload` there. (Or you could use the more modern `addEventListener()` etc.)

Comment: @Pointy Post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload` is a JavaScript property, not an HTML attribute.

HTML attributes do not have a `.` in them.

There is no `window` attribute in HTML.

There is no `onload` attribute for an `h3` element (since it doesn't trigger the loading of any content).

If you were writing code in the 90s you would:

```
<body onload="loadQuestion1()">
```

Code from the 00s would typically use:

```
window.onload = loadQuestion1;
```

Code from this decade typically uses:

```
addEventListener('load', loadQuestion1);
```

Comment: Where would i add the addEventListener('load', loadQuestion1); ?

Comment: More or less anywhere (in JS).

Answer (score 0):

You should delete code window.onload= "loadQuestion1()" from h3 tag and add onload= "loadQuestion1()" to body tag.

This should work.

This is working code, you had also few syntax error in JS, please compare with your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="loadQuestion1()">
<section>
    <h3 id="q1" style="color:blue"></h3>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="answers" value="Css is 1">Answer 1</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 2</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 3</li>
        <li><input type="radio">Answer 4</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("53");

    var questions = Array["question 1", "question 2", "question 3", "question 4" ];

    function loadQuestion1() {
        console.log("q1");
        document.getElementById('q1').innerHTML = "text";
    }
    function rand(min, max) {

        var offset = min;
        var range = (max - min) + 1;
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + offset;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    randomNumber = rand(0, questions.length - 1);
    randomQuestions = questions[randomNumber];
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your JS in this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    /*YOUR JS HERE*/
}
```

The window.onload event start when the document's window is ready